# upload multiple images and docs from multiple pages to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I have a `PageView` in flutter where there are 10 pages. On each page, the user can select and upload multiple images and multiple docs.
So page 1 => Multiple images & docs
page 2 => Multiple images and docs
and so on. So I have the code to loop and upload the data to Firebase, But the problem is that I can't figure out how to assign more than one `downloadURL` to a key.
Here's the upload code.

```dart
Future updateAdditionalProofOfDebt(
    String? iou,
    String? iouDoc,
    String? invoice,
    String? invoiceDoc,
    String? receipt,
    String? receiptDoc,
    String? contractAgreement,
    String? contractAgreementDoc,
    String? dopo,
    String? dopoDoc,
    String? emailCorrespondence,
    String? emailCorrespondenceDoc,
    String? smsWhatsApp,
    String? smsWhatsAppDoc,
    String? others,
    String? othersDoc,
    String? alloyWheels,
    String? alloyWheelsDoc,
    String? equipment,
    String? equipmentDoc,
  ) async {
    return await _firestore.collection('auctionPosts').doc(docid).update({
      'iou': iou,
      'iouDoc': iouDoc,
      'invoice': invoice,
      'invoiceDoc': invoiceDoc,
      'receipt': receipt,
      'receiptDoc': receiptDoc,
      'contractAgreement': contractAgreement,
      'contractAgreementDoc': contractAgreementDoc,
      'dopo': dopo,
      'dopoDoc': dopoDoc,
      'emailCorrespondence': emailCorrespondence,
      'emailCorrespondenceDoc': emailCorrespondenceDoc,
      'smsWhatsApp': smsWhatsApp,
      'smsWhatsAppDoc': smsWhatsAppDoc,
      'others': others,
      'othersDoc': othersDoc,
      'alloyWheels': alloyWheels,
      'alloyWheelsDoc': alloyWheelsDoc,
      'equipment': equipment,
      'equipmentDoc': equipmentDoc,
    });
  }
```

Here's the code where i'm uploading the data to firebase.

```
 ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                firebase_storage.Reference ref1;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref2;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref3;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref4;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref5;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref6;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref7;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref8;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref9;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref10;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref11;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref12;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref13;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref14;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref15;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref16;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref17;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref18;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref19;
                firebase_storage.Reference ref20;

                for (var item in file1) {
                  ref1 = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
                      .ref()
                      .child('images/${Path.basename(item.path)}');
                  await ref1.putFile(item).whenComplete(() async {
                    await ref1.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
                      for (var item in file2) {
                        ref2 = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
                            .ref()
                            .child('docs/${Path.basename(item.path)}');
                        ref2.putFile(item).whenComplete(() async {
                          await ref2.getDownloadURL().then((value2) {
                            for (var item in file3) {
                              ref3 = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
                                  .ref()
                                  .child('images/${Path.basename(item.path)}');
                              ref3.putFile(item).whenComplete(() async {
                                await ref3.getDownloadURL().then((value3) {
                                  for (var item in file4) {
                                    ref4 = firebase_storage
                                        .FirebaseStorage.instance
                                        .ref()
                                        .child(
                                            'images/${Path.basename(item.path)}');
                                    ref4.putFile(item).whenComplete(() async {
                                      await ref4
                                          .getDownloadURL()
                                          .then((value4) {
                                        DatabaseService(docid: widget.auid)
                                            .updateAdditionalProofOfDebt(
                                                value,
                                                value2,
                                                value3,
                                                value4,
                                                'value5',
                                                'value6',
                                                'value7',
                                                'value8',
                                                'value9',
                                                'value10',
                                                'value11',
                                                'value12',
                                                'value13',
                                                'value14',
                                                'value15',
                                                'value16',
                                                'value17',
                                                'value18',
                                                'value19',
                                                'value20');
                                      });
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                              });
                            }
                          });
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  });
                }
                print('Files uploaded: ${widget.auid}');
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Files uploaded Successfully!');
              },
              child: Text('Upload'))
```

For testing purpose i'm ignoring the other values...
The problem is even when i select 2 or more files in firebase only 1 downloadURL is stored.

```
invoice: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/financial-recovery.appspot.com/o/images%2FScreenshot_20211204-144142.jpg?alt=media&token=6b5338fe-3458-4a12-8a6a-daf2343e5c6a"
invoiceDoc: "value4"
iou: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/financial-recovery.appspot.com/o/images%2FScreenshot_20211128-163348_Video%20Player.jpg?alt=media&token=6ef2cdb0-0e93-4ff3-afa6-569cccae444a"
iouDoc: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/financial-recovery.appspot.com/o/images%2Fsaeedbacha.docx?alt=media&token=c00ee273-76b9-4356-94ce-224a64b4ab06"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it may have something to do with this async loop, try using Future.forEach for async loops

Comment: the first image downloadurl is uploaded correctly and then i guess it's replaced by the second one... I just need to find a way to store multiple download links in single key.
Or maybe create multiple keys for multiple downloadURL's ?